# How to avoid run-time checks for running parts of code that become unreachable after compilation?

Tags: c++

My program gets a couple of Boolean variables from the user, and their values won't change afterwards. Each Boolean variable enables a part of code. Something like this:

```
#include <iostream>

void callback_function(bool task_1, bool task_2, bool task_3) {
  if (task_1) {
    std::cout << "Running task 1" << std::endl;
  }
  if (task_2) {
    std::cout << "Running task 2" << std::endl;
  }
  if (task_3) {
    std::cout << "Running task 3" << std::endl;
  }
}

int main() {
  bool task_1 = true;
  bool task_2 = false;
  bool task_3 = true;

  while (true) {
    callback_function(task_1, task_2, task_3);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Now my question is, since the Boolean variables are fixed every time the program calls `callback_function()`, is there a way to avoid the `if` statements inside the callback function?

This is one way to avoid the run-time checks (implement a callback function for all permutations of the Boolean variables --- only two cases are shown below):

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

void callback_function_for_tasks_1_2_3() {
  std::cout << "Running task 1" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Running task 2" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Running task 3" << std::endl;
}

void callback_function_for_tasks_1_3() {
  std::cout << "Running task 1" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Running task 3" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
  bool task_1 = true;
  bool task_2 = false;
  bool task_3 = true;

  std::function<void()> callback_function;
  if (task_1 && task_2 && task_3) {
    callback_function = callback_function_for_tasks_1_2_3;
  } else if (task_1 && !task_2 && task_3) {
    callback_function = callback_function_for_tasks_1_3;
  }

  while (true) {
    callback_function();
  }

  return 0;
}
```

The problem is I have to implement `2^n` different callback functions, if there are `n` Boolean variables. Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: If you’re interested in performance, don’t use `std::function` when a function pointer will do.

Comment: Have you actually measured whether these conditional statements make a difference? This looks like a pretty pointless optimization effort to me. Or, if you're trying to solve an actual problem with this, it may be the wrong approach, a so-called "XY problem". Please, as a new user, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: If you go with with the 2nd approach, I believe, you will end up doing more checks then the 1st approch.   

Because each compound checks you are doing in the 2nd one will computationally cost you more than the 1st.  

I am not sure what are you trying to accomplish here, but if your concern is that for a false flag, the statements inside the block will take time to execute, then you don't have to worry about that.  

Because if the flag is false, the block will not take any execution time. And checking 1 by 1 will be cheaper than the combinations.

Comment: @ABMRuman He'd be doing more checks only once, not every time in the loop. If this is a long running application... One could safe quite a lot of checks if one combined the conditions inside an unsigned int/uint32_t/uint64_t (depending on number of checks) and select the function via a `switch` statement. The functions might be generated via a template function using `if constexpr` inside, so one wouldn't need to write all the functions explicitly.

Comment: Joining @UlrichEckhardt: You should first run a profiler to find the hottest spots to optimise. Optimising the called functions at the right places will most likely bring you much more performance gain than avoiding these view `if`s...

Comment: @Aconcagua sure, if all the possible combinations are known beforehand, one can simply do what you are suggesting. But if not, then configuring combinations for `n` is quite a hassle. Also, I could be looking at this wrong.

Comment: @ABMRuman Well, one could *generate* all (theoretically) possible combinations with a template – see [this anser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55438380/1312382). Problem is we'd need to select appropriate implementation at runtime. Left a comment for at the answer. Still I stay with – most likely you gain (much) more by optimising the code executed *inside* the `if` *bodies* first.

Comment: To avoid run-time checks, you simply do not use code that will run. So use either macros or metaprogramming in C++, those are basically instructions for the compiler and will never run after compiled.

Comment: Mandatory “premature optimization is the root of all evil”

Answer (score 15):

#### Ensuring that if statements are evaluated at compile time

C++17 introduces `if constexpr`, which does exactly this:

```
template<bool task_1, bool task_2, bool task_3>
void callback_function() {
  if constexpr (task_1) {
    std::cout << "Running task 1" << std::endl;
  }
  if constexpr (task_2) {
    std::cout << "Running task 2" << std::endl;
  }
  if constexpr (task_3) {
    std::cout << "Running task 3" << std::endl;
  }
}
```

**If you have optimizations enabled, `if constexpr` isn't necessary.** Even if you use a regular `if` instead of `if constexpr`, because the bools are now templated, the compiler will be able to eliminate the `if` statements entirely, and just run the tasks. [If you look at the assembly produced here](https://godbolt.org/z/tHpHIm), you'll see that even at `-O1`, there are no if statements in any of the `callback` functions.

We can now use `callback_function` directly as a function pointer, avoiding `function<void()>`:

```
int main() {
  using callback_t = void(*)();
  callback_t func = callback_function<true, false, true>;

  // Do stuff with func 
}
```

We can also name the `bool`s by assigning them to constexpr variables:

```
int main() {
  using callback_t = void(*)();
  constexpr bool do_task1 = true;
  constexpr bool do_task2 = false;
  constexpr bool do_task3 = true; 
  callback_t func = callback_function<do_task1, do_task2, do_task3>;

  // Do stuff with func 
}
```

#### Automatically creating a lookup table of all possible callback functions

You mentioned choosing between different callback functions at runtime. We can do this pretty easily with a lookup table, and we can use templates to *automatically* create a lookup table of all possible callback functions.

The first step is to get a callback function from a particular index:

```
// void(*)() is ugly to type, so I alias it
using callback_t = void(*)();

// Unpacks the bits 
template<size_t index>
constexpr auto getCallbackFromIndex() -> callback_t 
{
    constexpr bool do_task1 = (index & 4) != 0;
    constexpr bool do_task2 = (index & 2) != 0;
    constexpr bool do_task3 = (index & 1) != 0; 
    return callback_function<do_task1, do_task2, do_task3>; 
}
```

Once we can do that, we can write a function to create a lookup table from a bunch of indexes. Our lookup table will just be a `std::array`.

```
// Create a std::array based on a list of flags
// See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence
// For more information
template<size_t... Indexes>
constexpr auto getVersionLookup(std::index_sequence<Indexes...>) 
    -> std::array<callback_t, sizeof...(Indexes)>
{
    return {getCallbackFromIndex<Indexes>()...}; 
}

// Makes a lookup table containing all 8 possible callback functions
constexpr auto callbackLookupTable = 
    getVersionLookup(std::make_index_sequence<8>());
```

Here, `callbackLookupTable` contains all 8 possible callback functions, where `callbackLookupTable[i]` expands the bits of `i` to get the callback. For example, if `i == 6`, then `i`'s bits are `110` in binary, so

`callbackLookupTable[6]` is `callback_function<true, true, false>`

#### Using the lookup table at runtime

Using the lookup table is really simple. We can get an index from a bunch of `bool`s by bitshifting:

```
callback_t getCallbackBasedOnTasks(bool task1, bool task2, bool task3) {
    // Get the index based on bit shifting
    int index = ((int)task1 << 2) + ((int)task2 << 1) + ((int)task3); 
    // return the correct callback
    return callbackLookupTable[index]; 
}
```

#### Example demonstrating how to read in tasks

We can get the `bool`s at runtime now, and just call `getCallbackBasedOnTasks` to get the correct callback

```
int main() {
    bool t1, t2, t3;
    // Read in bools
    std::cin >> t1 >> t2 >> t3; 
    // Get the callback
    callback_t func = getCallbackBasedOnTasks(t1, t2, t3); 
    // Invoke the callback
    func(); 
}
```

Comment: The `constexpr` is IMHO a red herring, the important part is the use of template parameters which are evaluated at compile time. Any halfway-decent compiler is able to figure this out even without these `consexpr` hints.

Comment: I updated the answer explaining how to automatically generate a list of all possible callback functions. You can find the right one just by packing the bools into the bits of the index

Comment: The lookup table *is* a runtime solution. You can get the right function just by indexing into it

Comment: (@$#*!) – can't find anything to criticise any more... Just kidding. But the automatically created lookup table is *great*, far better than my originally proposed `switch` statement...

Comment: Thank you! I cleaned up the answer a bit to make it more readable. Having **Addendum** all over the place was kinda ugly, so that was a good suggestion, and some parts of the code were kinda messy. 

Also, if you wanna explore automatically generated lookup tables further, I'd recommend researching `std::visit`. It's possible to implement `std::visit` really efficiently using them

Answer (score 1):

Leave the code as it is.

Execution time of an "if" compared to writing to std::out is practically zero, so you are arguing over nothing. Well, unless you spend some time measuring the execution time as it is, and with the if's removed according to the values of the three constants, and found that there is a real difference.

At most, you might make the function inline or static, and the compiler will probably realise the arguments are always the same when optimisation is turned on. (My compiler would give a warning that you are using a function without a prototype, which means you should have either put a prototype into a header file, telling the compiler to expect calls from other call sites, or you should have made it static, telling the compiler that it knows all the calls and can use static analysis for optimisations).

And what you think is a constant, might not stay a constant forever. The original code will work. Any new code most likely won't.

Comment: **If** the call is inlined into the loop, the compiler might hoist the tests, but it’s unlikely for more than a variable or two because of the code size increase.

Answer (score 0):

Short of JIT compilation, you can’t do better than your 2^n functions (and the resulting binary size).  You can of course use a **template** to avoid writing them all out.  To prevent the source from scaling exponentially just from selecting the correct implementation, you can write a recursive dispatcher ([demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/7EGn8oxqTQtjpxfd)):

```
template<bool... BB>
auto g() {return f<BB...>;}
template<bool... BB,class... TT>
auto g(bool b,TT... tt)
{return b ? g<BB...,true>(tt...) : g<BB...,false>(tt...);}
```

Comment: If you know something at compiletime, it's easy to template it. Especially in the OP's case.

Comment: @JorgePerez: I did say that you could use a template.  I do realize now that you can put some of the `if`s inside intermediate templates; I’ll edit that in.